# How to Send an Array Over HTTPPost

Tags: java, android, http

I have to send these parameters over httppost. From my android app to a drupal server.

This is the php representation

```
$data = array(
        'node' => array(
            'type' => 'celapp_order',
            'title' => 'order celeb: nixon-fan '.date("j.m.Y H:i:s"),
            'field_fan_uid' => array(0 => array('uid' => 4)),
            'field_celeb_uid' => array(0 => array('uid' => 5)),
            'field_celeb_price' => array(0 => array('value' => 0.79))
        )
    );
```

In the past I have used namevaluepairs. I cannot work out how to send the parameters using namevaluepairs. If anybody can help I will be very greatful

Comment: Your array is shown in PHP syntax.  How is it represented in java?  Hashtable?  Hashmap?  something else?  Are you sending it from android to another server or from another server?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't so clear. I am sending it from Android to a drupal server. Its not represented in java. I have lots of strings that I need to populate the array with then send over Httppost

Comment: As Marc B put in answer, you should use json encoding to pass a data structure like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a JSON wrapper:

```
$postable = json_encode($data); // in PHP, there's equivalents for Java out there.
```

That'll convert the array into plaintext (basically javascript) which is easy to send via POST. the receiving end would use `json_decode()` (or whatever its equivalent is on that particular platform) to convert from the JSON version back to a native array/object.

Answer (score 0):

I've used **[GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)** with great results for serializing/deserializing JSON ro and from plain old java objects (POJOs). Link to array examples **[here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Array-Examples)**.

e.g.:

```
public class Foo {

    private string Bar;
    private int Num;
}

Foo[] foos = new Foo[] ... // create array here

Gson gson = new Gson();
String text = gson.toJson(foos);

/*
output: 

[
  {
     "Bar" : "Hello",
     "Num" : 25
  },
  {
     "Bar" : "World",
     "Num" : 42,
  }
]

*/
```